# If I rebase (squash) a git history, will the files from the squashed commits removed?

Tags: git, gitlab, rebase

Assuming I have a git branch, with lot of commits there always a few files replaces with new ones.

Lets say: The initial commit contains file.txt with the content "1". The the last commit contains file.txt with the content "100". Any commit between them contains file.txt with a number between 1 and 100.

However, I can rebase the hostory and squash them all together.
After that, I have for exampel two commits. The inital with content "1" and the last with content "100".

What happen with the other ones?

Obviously, in my real example the files are larger ones. I alreaady tried it on a local copy and check the size of the .git directory, but this doesn't change. So I thik theystill exist somethere in the .git dir, but not accessible. How can I get rid of them?

(the origin repo is on a self hosted gitlab instance)

Thanks

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26080278/can-i-save-space-in-a-git-repo-by-squashing-commits

Answer (score 0):

Git will periodically clean up unreachable commits. You can trigger it manually with `git gc` if you want.